# Do we need the [colors] tag?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags

I can see no real use in having this tag, which is currently only used in [one question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37946/a-maze-of-colors). Should we remove this tag? If not, why not? I yes, why?

Comment: Merge it to [tag:visual]?

Comment: @f'' Why not?''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to have already been removed, so this can be safely marked as [status-completed] whenever a mod sees it.

Comment: ahah you may be able to do it yourself in a few hours

Comment: @Lordofdark Indeed!